# Adjusting the image and text blocks with zoom-in effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place the text at the bottom of the image while the image `zoom-in` effect can be triggered by placing the mouse on the text+image. Also, the image height should remain same or at least within its placeholder and not over the text.

**Note: The image has an overlay but it currently is everywhere :(**

How should I proceed? I'm stuck.
**http://jsfiddle.net/6bgxn2s4/**

HTML:

```css
.zoom-group{
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000; 
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
  text-align: center;
}
.zoom-text {
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.zoom-bottom {
  color: #444;
}
.zoom-block img{
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.zoom-link {
    display: block;
}
.zoom-block:hover img{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-group">
 <a class="zoom-link" href="#" >
   <div class="zoom-block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    <div class="zoom-text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom-bottom">
    This is the title and I would like to have the zoom effect called when I place my mouse here too! 
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is what you look for I can add it as an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/6bgxn2s4/2/ ... here with gray background http://jsfiddle.net/6bgxn2s4/3/

Comment: Almost there but I actually want the `<div class="zoom-bottom">` to be able to trigger the image zoom-in effect too. Would that be possible? My update: http://jsfiddle.net/6bgxn2s4/4/

Comment: Yes, 2 ways, either when hover the zoom-link or with a flexbox trick. I'll post an answer in a sec

Comment: Posted an answer. Let me know which of the 2 you prefer and I'll add an explanation for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that transform:scale always overlap other containers. Because it's not changing the actual height and with of the element.

A workaround could be that you are changing the width on hover:

```css
.zoom-group{
  border: 1px solid #000000; 
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
  text-align: center;
  width:250px;
}

.zoom-block {
  position:relative;
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}

.zoom-text {
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.zoom-bottom {
  color: #444;
}
.zoom-block img{
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
  display:block;
   width:250px;
}
.zoom-link {
    display: block;
}
.zoom-group:hover .zoom-block img{
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-group">
 <a class="zoom-link" href="#" >
 
 
   <div class="zoom-block">
   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    <div class="zoom-text"></div>
    
    
  </div>
  <div class="zoom-bottom">
    This is the title and I would like to have the zoom effect called when I place my mouse here too! 
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't cleared enough in my explanation. The height of the image has to remain constant. Also, the overlay must be only on the image and not on the entire container. Could you help?

Comment: Yeah sure. Gimme a sec.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait :)

Comment: What you mean with overlay? Which class?

Comment: Line 17 of http://jsfiddle.net/6bgxn2s4/ where the opacity of the image is set to 0.3

Comment: Is that the first thing you want? I edited it. The link i can make hover able after i know which effect you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you. However, it doesn't solve the core issue which is to trigger the image on hover. "zoom-bottom" class must be able to trigger the zoom-in effect too. Thank You once again for your time.

Comment: That is no Problem. Wait.

Comment: Need the link to be on the whole area? Looks weird to me

Comment: I just did what i think you are looking forward to. Or you need it full with with only the link and the image hovered

Answer (score 2):

Here is 2 ways, where the first use a `flexbox` trick, where it zoom only on image and bottom text.

You simply change the markup order of the `zoom-block` and `zoom-bottom` elements, and then reorder them again, using the flexbox property `order`.

When done like that you can use the sibling selector `+` to target the image when hover the text since it in the markup is *before*, though visually *after*.

*I also changed the image to `display: block` (it will behave better when scale), added a new rule for `zoom-block`, so it adjust to image size, cut the overflow when image scale, and position the overlay text on top of the image*

```css
.zoom-group{
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000; 
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
  text-align: center;
}
.zoom-text {  
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.zoom-bottom {
  color: #444;
}
.zoom-block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.zoom-block img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.zoom-link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.zoom-bottom {
    order: 1;
}

.zoom-bottom:hover + .zoom-block img,
.zoom-block:hover img{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-group">
 <a class="zoom-link" href="#" >
   <div class="zoom-bottom">
    This is the title and I would like to have the zoom effect called when I place my mouse here too! 
   </div>
   <div class="zoom-block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    <div class="zoom-text">Hello zoom text</div>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

---

The second, set the `:hover` on the `zoom-link` element instead of the `zoom-block`

```css
.zoom-group{
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000; 
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
  text-align: center;
}
.zoom-text {  
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.zoom-bottom {
  color: #444;
}
.zoom-block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.zoom-block img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.zoom-link {
    display: block;
}
.zoom-link:hover img{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-group">
 <a class="zoom-link" href="#" >
   <div class="zoom-block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    <div class="zoom-text">Hello zoom text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom-bottom">
    This is the title and I would like to have the zoom effect called when I place my mouse here too! 
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Main concern is transform:scale which overlaps other containers as it's not changing the actual height and width of the element.

```css
.zoom-group{
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000; 
  display: block; 
  position: relative; 
  text-align: center;
}
.zoom-text {
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.zoom-bottom {
  color: #444;
}
.zoom-block img{
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
  display:block;
   width:250px;
   height:auto;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
}
.zoom-link {
    display: block;
}
.zoom-block:hover img{
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-group">
 <a class="zoom-link" href="#" >
   <div class="zoom-block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    <div class="zoom-text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom-bottom">
    This is the title and I would like to have the zoom effect called when I place my mouse here too! 
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you just copied and pasted the other answer?!! Am I missing something here?

Comment: No I was trying it and while posted I saw someone else already posted an answer.